# Can create food & drink make soda pop?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, food-and-drink

Would create the create food and drink spell create soda pop if the caster actually drank such a item once or do you need to make it via alchemy?

Comment: Closed: user sockpuppeting around a suspension.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[No, because the spell can only create normal water](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/createFoodAndWater.htm):

> **Create Food and Water**
>   The food that this spell creates is simple fare of your choice—highly nourishing, if rather bland. Food so created decays and becomes inedible within 24 hours, although it can be kept fresh for another 24 hours by casting a purify food and drink spell on it. **The water created by this spell is just like clean rain water, and it doesn’t go bad as the food does.**

So no fizzy drinks for the cleric.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75040/discussion-on-answer-by-thomas-jacobs-can-create-food-drink-make-soda-pop).

Comment: Wasn't this spell one of the reasons why every mage takes *Prestidigitation*? Which, by the way, **would** allow one to make the water appear and taste like soda pop.

Comment: RAW Prestidigitation cannot carbonate a beverage, but it can alter the taste.